# ¿Como mostrar las iniciales de un span dentro de una tabla con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta tabla, el cual quiero que solo me muestre las iniciales del texto `SPAN`, en el script logro realizarlo, pero a la hora de implementarlo en toda la tabla solo me toma el primer valor.

Ejemplo en Cierre me toma como P en vez de mostrar una C.

```js
$('table tr .status').each(function(){
    var name = $('.status').text();
    var initials = name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
    initials = ((initials.shift() || '') + (initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
    $('.status').text(initials);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Estado con iniciales</td>
      <td>Estado Original</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td><span class="status">Prospecto</span></td>
      <td>Prospecto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Curabitur</td>
      <td><span class="status">Detección de Necesidades</span></td>
      <td>Detección de Necesidades</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Donec</td>
      <td><span class="status">Cierre</span></td>
      <td>Cierre</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien la respuesta de Felipe me parece más adecuada al usar puro css y no meter js, creo que es importante saber cuál era el error de tu código actual.

Estabas usando `$('.status')` dentro del each, lo que traía siempre el primero, por lo que cambiando los `$('.status')` por `$(this)` como en el código siguiente, funciona tu código.

```js
$('table tr .status').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    var initials = name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
    initials = ((initials.shift() || '') + (initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
    $(this).text(initials);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Estado con iniciales</td>
      <td>Estado Original</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td><span class="status">Prospecto</span></td>
      <td>Prospecto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Curabitur</td>
      <td><span class="status">Detección de Necesidades</span></td>
      <td>Detección de Necesidades</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Donec</td>
      <td><span class="status">Cierre</span></td>
      <td>Cierre</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que lo hagas con CSS, que te parece de esta manera.
Indicamos que el texto se ocultara, y luego solo mostramos la primera letra.

> Para usar :first-letter se necesita primero bloquear el contenedor de este, por lo cual a status le asigno un style display:block, luego lo oculto, para todo trabajarlo desde el pseudo-elemento.

```css
.status {
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.status:first-letter {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Estado con iniciales</td>
      <td>Estado Original</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td><span class="status">Prospecto</span></td>
      <td>Prospecto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Curabitur</td>
      <td><span class="status">Detección de Necesidades</span></td>
      <td>Detección de Necesidades</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Donec</td>
      <td><span class="status">Cierre</span></td>
      <td>Cierre</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: por que un display block y un visibility hidden juntos en la misma regla?

Comment: Tengo entendido que para usar :first-letter necesitas primero dejar en block el principal, luego de esto lo pongo oculto, porque al usar el pseudoelemento solo mostrare firstletter

Comment: Son esos detalles los que uno debe compartir en la respuesta, de ese modo quien la use sabrá el por que de las cosas ;)

Comment: Gracias, ya lo edite.